# Hide or remove search filters woocommerce orders

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

It is posible to hide or remove filters options on woocommerce bulk order panel? I created custom fields on woocommerce checkout and I don't want shop manager use this filter to search orders because I don't want to confuse him. Can I do it with some code in php?

Here are some images to explain what I want to remove.

If it is possible, I would like to remove customer search too.

Thank you!
[image]

EDITED QUESTION: I already can hide "field name" (nombre del campo) search filter. Can I do the same with customer search?